# Azure Mobile Service - Consume POST Operation With Complex Type Parameter

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I have created a custom controller with the following method:

```
// POST api/CustomLogin
public HtpResponseMessage Post(LoginRequest loginRequest)
{
     // ...
}
```

Where a LoginRequest is:

```
public class LoginRequest
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

How can I use the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceClient to consume this operation? I was expecting to use InvokeApiAsync but I can only see two overrides, neither of which allow me to pass content in the request message.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to do something like:

```
var loginParams = new LoginRequest() { ... };
var result = await Client.invokeApiAsync<LoginResult, string>("CustomLogin", loginParams);
```

Any one of these will give you options to control the request content, with the first one giving you complete control on the content & response.

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> InvokeApiAsync(string apiName, 
  HttpContent content, HttpMethod method, IDictionary<string, string> 
  requestHeaders, IDictionary<string, string> parameters)

public async Task<U> InvokeApiAsync<T, U>(string apiName, T body, 
  HttpMethod method, IDictionary<string, string> parameters)

public async Task<JToken> InvokeApiAsync(string apiName, JToken body,    
  HttpMethod method, IDictionary<string, string> parameters)
```

Comment: Information can be found here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn268388.aspx

Comment: You saved my day. I was having problems trying to send the object as a string Json. But this solved it. Thank you.